# How to use avg and partition by properly?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a data containing `user_ids`, `visitStartTime` and `product prices`, that have been viewed by a user. I try get average and max price for each user's visit, but my query does not make calculation on partition (user+visitStartTime), it makes calculations by `user_id` partition only.

Here is my query:

```
select distinct fullVisitorId ,visitStartTime,
    avg(pr) over (partition by visitStartTime,fullVisitorId) as avgPrice,
    max(pr) over (partition by fullVisitorId,visitStartTime) as maxPrice
from dataset
```

Here is what I got:

```
+-----+----------------------+-----------------+----------+----------+--+
| Row |    fullVisitorId     |    visitStartTi | avgPrice | maxPrice |  |
+-----+----------------------+-----------------+----------+----------+--+
|   1 |    64217461724617261 |      1538478049 |    484.5 |    969.0 |  |
|   2 |    64217461724617261 |      1538424725 |    484.5 |    969.0 |  |
+-----+----------------------+-----------------+----------+----------+--+
```

What am I missing in my query?

Sample Data

```
+---------------+----------------+---------------+
| FullVisitorId | VisitStartTime | ProductPrice  |
+---------------+----------------+---------------+
|           123 |       72631241 |           100 |
|           123 |       72631241 |           250 |
|           123 |       72631241 |            10 |
|           123 |       73827882 |            70 |
|           123 |       73827882 |            90 |
+---------------+----------------+---------------+
```

Desired result:

```
+-----+---------------+--------------+----------+----------+
| Row | fullVisitorId | visitStartTi | avgPrice | maxPrice |
+-----+---------------+--------------+----------+----------+
|   1 |           123 |     72631241 |    120.0 |    250.0 |
|   2 |           123 |     73827882 |     80.0 |     90.0 |
+-----+---------------+--------------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: I am using BigQuery.

Comment: Use a simple aggregate query. No need for window functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need 'partition by' in this case.

Try this:

```
select fullVisitorId ,visitStartTime, avg(ProductPrice) avgPrice ,max(ProductPrice) maxPrice
from sample
group by FullVisitorId,VisitStartTime;
```

(The query is pretty standard so I think you can use that in BigQuery)

Here is the output using PostgreSQL: [DB<>FIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=b511450f484f4bbb2feb539c20bbf3c3)

**Update**

Also works with BigQuery Standard SQL:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  FullVisitorId, 
  VisitStartTime, 
  AVG(ProductPrice) as avgPrice,
  MAX(ProductPrice) as maxPrice
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY FullVisitorId, VisitStartTime
```

If you want to test it:

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 123 FullVisitorId, 72631241 VisitStartTime, 100 ProductPrice 
  UNION ALL SELECT 123, 72631241, 250
  UNION ALL SELECT 123, 72631241, 10
  UNION ALL SELECT 123, 73827882, 70
  UNION ALL SELECT 123, 73827882, 90
)

SELECT 
  FullVisitorId, 
  VisitStartTime, 
  AVG(ProductPrice) as avgPrice,
  MAX(ProductPrice) as maxPrice
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY FullVisitorId, VisitStartTime
```